# Collective web chat

Tags: sql-server, database, schema

I need to develop a web chat with one "advanced" feature: grouping chat - like the Skype's chatting system.

The theory is trivial, but in practice it is very hard. Since last friday I was thinking about this, but I have no idea of how I can apply this architecture. Basically I need a database's design with a good structure without store redundancy.

Ok....... so far it seems simple, but now I'll introduce our main feature: history by user.

I can create one chat with 2 users. Ok, two days passed and I want to add a third user to join the conversation. The chat's history for him will be different: he will not be able to view old messages in that chat.

Wonderful, huh? Remember, friends: I can not use XML to store the history locally. I NEED to user a SQL Database. In my case, I'm using SQL-Server, from Microsoft.

Can you all understand my problem? If yes, isn't trivial, huh? Ok. Can someone think how I can solve this problem? I'm going crazy!

Comment: Please put only relevant information in your question. State a clear question and leave out the unnecessary details of what you have been thinking. Short, to the point questions help others to help you getting an answer faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem *is* trivial. Storing it in XML would be the real problem.

- Users (UserId, Name)
- Chat (ChatId, ChatName)
- ChatParticipation (ChatParticipationId, UserId, JoinChatMessageId, LeaveMessageId)
- ChatMessages (ChatMessageId, ChatId, UserId, Message)

By adding the `ChatParticipation` table you will know exactly which is the `ChatMessageId` at which the user joined the chat (`JoinChatMessageId`) and don't show him messages prior messages. `LeaveMessageId` can track when he left the chat room. Multiple join/leaves can be modeled as separate participation.

Comment: Now the "thing" is clearly for me. You open my mind - really! I was hindering it was easy. I will work based in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what language (PHP etc).. So it's kinda hard, but, if I was creating this from a PHP point of view I would have the chat based upon id's. www.site.com/chat.php?id={id} and then have a way to accept / decline the user accordingly.

> I can create one chat with 2 users. Ok, two days passed and I want to add a third user to join the conversation. The chat's history for him will be different: he will not be able to view old messages in that chat.

Why not give each message a date and a time, and then when a user member enters the chat, they can only see the messages from this date/time? This could work in theory.

So if I joined the chat today at 15:20pm then I can only see messages on or after 15:21.

Your main problem is going to displaying the messages in real-time, because it is a web application..

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Phorce. I'm working with C#.NET/AJAX/Server Push to make this chat application. I was thinking about this, but this will not be redundant?

Comment: I don't get what you mean 'redundant' - You want a way to prevent users who have just joined from see previous chat, correct? So, if I joined the chat when it was first created, I will still be able to see the chat whereas if I have just joined, the chat won't be visible to me, but, will still be there. There shouldn't be any redundancies

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, whether I understand your problem correctly.

As far as I understand it, you need 4 tables: 
user (userid, username), 
conversation (conversationid, conversationtitle), 
user_conversation (userid, conversationid) 
post (userid, conversationid, text)

user stores all users registered in your system. conversation stores all conversations. user_conversation maps theusers to the conversations they are allowed into. Post stores the posts a user has made in a certain conversation.

Now you can simply retrieve data from post by user, by conversation or both. If you dont want a user to see older posts, add a date field.

Regards

Luigi